# WWW: Many pages to one?

Tags: text-processing, web, document-converter

We have a documentation/help system in the form of 'a lot of www pages (one-topic-per-page)'.

Is there any ready-to-go software/script able to change that docs to 'all-in-one-page' format?

Comment: Second answer I've found to my question is: 'use calibre' - see:
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28741/convert-table-of-contents-into-single-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that they are all linked you can use [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html) to combine them into a single document in a number of formats. They can be locally stored or online.

About Pandoc:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Available for Windows, OS-X and Linux
- Available as source code